# How to make keys pressed appear on screen

Tags: 16.04, keyboard

So in windows, you can make the keys pressed appear on screen. I was wondering, is that possible in ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the packages `screenkey` or `key-mon`

Comment: Screenkey github page for installation instructions: https://github.com/wavexx/screenkey/

Comment: Florian, You're showing up in the LQ review queue...  (Voted "Looks OK" but you should expand a bit)  **:P**